Global entry not approved in portal 2 weeks after verbal approval by CBP offers at enrollment on arrival interview
Global entry was conditionally approved while I was out on travel in Europe. So went to the enrollment on arrival (EoA) interview after I landed back into the USA after the Europe trip.
As a permanent resident, I showed the following to officer:

permanent resident card
non-US passport
driver's license (of a US state where I'm resident)

Answered a few questions by CBP officer: state my name, what I do for a living, any travel out of the USA in the last 5 years, any customs violations (I said 'no', and officer asked again 'no customs violations?' I said 'no' again since that's the truth. Weird though that officer asked that twice.)
Verbal approval by officer ~Sept 18th. Officer said as a permanent resident, I won't receive the global entry card (?) and that I can enter by showing biometrics.
Today is Oct 1st (almost 2 weeks since the interview and verbal approval).
My TTP CBP portal for global entry still shows "conditionally approved" and no changes.
Questions:

Should I be concerned since it's been 2 weeks and still no approval?
Do I need to wait more? Is this time frame usual?
How should I reach out to CBP? For Illinois, it shows Chicago ORD and Chicago Enrollment Center and for both locations, no one ever picks up the phone on the phone numbers listed.


as a permanent resident, I won't receive the global entry card - I don't think that's true. See the first sentence here.

Posting the resolution of my case here for future visitors:
CBP called me back. Well, a contractor, who said they contracted for CBP, did. They inquired why I called the CBP number. When I explained, they asked for my pass ID / member ID and then went away for 15 seconds to ask an officer since they didn't have the right access as a contractor to know the details.
In the meantime, I got an email from TTP portal that app status has changed. I logged into the TTP portal and saw that I was approved. Apparently, it was some sort of oversight that they were able to quickly resolve.
So in my case, contacting CBP about the unusual delay caused them to take a look and fix whatever the issue was. Your mileage may vary but just wanted to share my case.
